# How to add xdebug to vagrant vm if it was installed using puphpet?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, xdebug, developer-tools, puphpet

I have a working VM based on a vagrant box.
It was created with help of a puphpet.
Now I need to add xdebug to the VM.
What is the best way to install xdebug?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you run php 7 on your server then you need to add

```
server:
install: '1'
packages: 
    - php-xdebug
```

to config.yml in your puphpet.

Then you need:

```
$: vagrant provision
```

and

```
$: vagrant up
```

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug is a first-class citizen in PuPHPet. Just add the following:

```
xdebug:
    install: 1
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
```

and `vagrant provision` to apply.